# Using a progressdialog and handler

Tags: java, android, handler, progressdialog

I'm working on an app that connect to a webpage to get some content. I want to show a progressdialog, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

This is my code:

```
        final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WhoisBeyondActivity.this, "Wait...", "Fetching data...", true);
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        // code to execute
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

The problem is that the progressdialog is only shown one second at the end of the operation I want to make. I think the progressdialog is only executing when I execute the dismiss() because it appears and dissapears quickly. Is like the progressdialog appears only to dissapear ... help me please!!! I have read a lot of tutorials, and I have try a lot of option, like THREAD instead of HANDLER, but it is not usefull for me, because I have to edit UI.

Comment: try using a separate thread for processing and progress dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent example and tutorial here:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

That's what I used the first time I did a threaded dialog in Android, and I bookmarked it.  Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the described behaviour is that the `post` method will just execute the passed in `runnable` against the thread to which the `Handler` is attached.  In your case this is the UI thread.

You are calling `ProgressDialog.show()`, which is asynchronous.  This does not actually show the dialog as soon as the method returns, rather you have just requested that the UI display a dialog.  You then immediately `post` a thread that sleeps for 2 seconds, which is added to the UI queue and blocks the UI from performing the dialog `show`.  The UI then wakes from your sleep, shows the dialog then is dismissed.

You should perform any network operation in either a new `Thread` or in an `AsyncTask`.  Have a look at these links for more details:

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Designing for responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- [Thread documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a separate thread per-say. What you really want is an [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). This will allow you to create the progress dialog and do the background processing right there in the task. Simple to write and easier to implement. If your refer to the link, what you need is actually really similar to your question. With a little tweaking, it should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    protected static final String TAG = "HelloActivity";
    ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //
        showDialog(1);
        final Handler handler=new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                //update UI here depending on what message is received.
                switch(msg.what){
                case 0:
                    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }

        };
        Thread t = new Thread(){

            public void run(){

                        try {
                            // code to execute
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);//nothing to send
                    }

        };
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HelloActivity.this, "Wait...", "Fetching data...", true);
        return myProgressDialog;
    }
}
```